# Questions about boundary faces of simplices and triangulations

Tags: geometry, general-topology

Let $S$ be a simplex in $\mathbf R^n$ and let $\{S_i\}$ be a triangulation of $S$.

1. The boundary of $S$ is defined as the union of the boundary faces of $S$. Is this union equal to the topological boundary of $S$ (with respect to the Euclidean norm topology)? The answer seems to be an obvious yes but I'm having trouble proving it. Any tips or references?
2. It seems to be a well established fact, although I have never seen it proved anywhere, that each boundary face of a subsimplex $S_i$ of the triangulation is either contained in a boundary face of $S$ or is shared by exactly one other subsimplex $S_j$. I have been trying to prove this for a while now and it seems highly nontrivial. The proof I am constructing relies on the answer to 1 being yes. Any tips or references are welcome.

Comment: For 2, does it help to remember that in a triangulated space (or simplicial complex) every point is in the interior of exactly one simplex?

Comment: This is just my ignorance showing, but what is a triangulation of a simplex?  For example, of a tetrahedron in $\mathbb{R}^3$?  My confusion is that a simplex is already triangulated, under one interpretation of "triangulation."

Comment: @Joseph A triangulation of an $n$-dimensional simplex $S$ is a finite collection of $n$-simplices, called the subsimplices of the triangulation, whose union equals S and such that the intersection of any two of them is a common face.

Comment: @wckronholm That cannot be true since two subsimplices may share a face.

Comment: @echoone Consider a single triangle (i.e. a 2-simplex). This space has one 2-simplex, three 1-simplices, and three 0-simplices. Then a point is either in the interior of the triangle (whence the interior of the 2-simplex), on one of the edges (whence the interior of one of the 1-simplices), or a vertex (which by convention is the interior of itself). Do you see how this extends to larger complexes?

Comment: @wckronholm I understand what you meant to say now, that is that every point of a simplex is an interior point of one of its faces. Let me think about what I can do with that.